# Pandas set a separator after the space

Tags: python, regex, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a text file structured like this:

```
  test1 test2                         data      world                        world          int             float          
  test3 test4 test5 test6             data      world                        world          int             float       
  test7 test8 test9                   data      world                        world                          float       
  test10 test11                       data      world         number         world          int             float  
  test12 test13                       data                    number         world          int             float
```

I should set a separator, the first couple of words are only separated by a space the others are unique but unfortunately not always recurring

I simply tried to replace a comma after three spaces and scale the commas gradually but where the middle word is missing I get a comma less!

i tried to import it with jupyter and pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:test.csv', sep = '\n',header=None,encoding = "utf-8" )
ad
df = df[0].str.split('\t', expand=True)
or
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:test.csv', sep = '\t' )
```

But nothing doesn't recognize the tab and spaces messes up the whole dataframe
I thought it would take a while but I got stuck
Does anyone have any suggestions!
Thanks

Comment: What is the actual separator between the fields? Could it be tab-separated?

Comment: Or are they fixed-width fields?

Comment: no unfortunately they are neither tabs nor have a fixed width!

Comment: Then I think you're screwed. How should it know that `number` on the last line is field 4 rather than field 3?

Comment: I'm afraid so ... and I thought it was easy

Comment: This is one of those things that's easy for humans because we can see the visual pattern. It's harder for computers.

Comment: I can only take the first two columns, the others I don't know ... I'm trying with a sort of grouping in pandas excluding the first two columns

Comment: If you can see any regularity in the pattern, you can use a regex. Else, there is no way. See https://regex101.com/r/j870Ff/1, adjust the max whitespace limit as you see fit in the regex.

Comment: thanks for the answer unfortunately there is no regularity, maybe I managed .. I should copy in a dummy column only integer values ​​with pandas df [4] = df [5] if integer, if you can help me with the syntax and I should have solved it!

Comment: I just miss this step, then I write what I invented.... even a line shift with only float numbers would be fine!